# ReleaseStrategy for iterators

Tags: spring-integration

Is there any way to use ReleaseStrategy, or simulate it, when I use split() with iterators?

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow flow(CourseRepository courseRepository, EnrollmentRepository enrollmentRepository) {
return IntegrationFlows.from(courseRepository, "findAllWithEnrollmentToProcess", c -> c
    .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(this.executionIntervalInSeconds, SECONDS)))
    .split()
        .transform(Course::getId)
        .transform(enrollmentRepository::findUnprocessedEnrollments)
        .split()
            .handle(...)
        // do something when split ends
    .get();
}
```

Both methods findAllWithEnrollmentToProcess and findUnprocessedEnrollments return an Iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that only with an `.aggregate()`. Twice in your case.

We have a similar sample in the XML configuration:

```
<splitter id="upstream-splitter" input-channel="splitter" output-channel="upstream-splits" />

<splitter id="downstream-splitter" input-channel="upstream-splits" output-channel="downstream-splits" />

<aggregator id="first-aggregator" input-channel="downstream-splits" output-channel="pre-output" />

<aggregator id="second-aggregator" input-channel="pre-output" />
```

But that is exactly the same for the Java DSL config.

Although your problem that you really have to figure out the proper `ReleaseStrategy` for you use-case since you may don't know the size of your iterators.

Comment: I'm not using .aggregate() anymore. Now, before .split() I save the iterator in a header and I .filter("headers['iterator'].hasNext()") with a discard channel.